# Should I update GeoLiteCity.dat periodically?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, geoip, kibana

Logstash can make use of a bundled GeoLiteCity.dat database for IP address geographical lookups. Is this database the same as [the one provided by MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite)? MaxMind updates the database on the first Tuesday of every month.

Would it be smart to set up a job to auto-refresh the database instead of waiting for updates to Logstash from ElasticSearch?

EDIT: Dec 1 2014
Here's the bash script I wrote to perform the auto-update of the databases. My  read of [the source code for this filter](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-geoip/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/geoip.rb) is that a service restart is probably required to take up the updated database files.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Downloads the latest GeoLight DBs from maxmind.
# Updates/replaces the databases that logstash uses.
# These are the IP-to-location databases that logstash uses.
# Maxmind updates them once a month on the first Tuesday of the month.
# See http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

echo Beginning update of GeoIP databases for logstash.
cd /tmp
rm -f GeoIPASNum.dat.gz GeoIPASNum.dat GeoLiteCity.dat.gz GeoLiteCity.dat
echo Downloading latest files.
wget --quiet --output-document GeoIPASNum.dat.gz http://download.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/asnum/GeoIPASNum.dat.gz || { echo 'Download of GeoIPASNum.dat.gz failed' ; exit 1; }
wget --quiet --output-document GeoLiteCity.dat.gz http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz || { echo 'Download of GeoLiteCity.dat.gz failed' ; exit 1; }

echo Unzipping
gunzip GeoIPASNum.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz

echo Setting permissions
chmod 664 GeoIPASNum.dat GeoLiteCity.dat
chown logstash:logstash GeoIPASNum.dat GeoLiteCity.dat

echo Replacing existing files and backing up the old.
cd /opt/logstash/vendor/geoip/
mv -f GeoIPASNum.dat GeoIPASNum.dat.bak && mv /tmp/GeoIPASNum.dat .
mv -f GeoLiteCity.dat GeoLiteCity.dat.bak && mv /tmp/GeoLiteCity.dat .

echo Restarting logstash
# Modify for your distro services model.
service logstash restart

echo Done
```

Comment: Found the source for the geo filter: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-geoip/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/geoip.rb  It reminded me that I could set in config an alternate location for these databases, which would likely be a better solution than overwriting the distributed databases.

Comment: Its silly to have to restart logstash every time a new GeoLiteCity.dat is dropped into place. I see there is an option to have "periodic_flush" but I am not sure what that does exactly or how often as all it says is: "Call the filter flush method at regular interval" (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-filters-geoip.html#plugins-filters-geoip-periodic_flush)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the same database, and yes, you can use updates from maxmind website. I use the `geoip-database-contrib` package in ubuntu which includes a cronjob to update the database files from maxmind automatically.

I don't how fast the maxmind dataset changes, but since logstash (which includes the database file) has a slow release schedule (current 1.4.2 was released 5 months ago), I use an up-to-date database.

Comment: It looks like you need a commercial license to receive regular updates?

Comment: See http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/: free updates every month. If you need more updates, you'll need to pay.

Comment: Looks good. Last question: Do you need to restart logstash to take up the updated .dat files?

Comment: Edited the question. My read of the source leads me to think a restart is required.